# Populate dropdown using a javascript object

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I am trying to populate a dropdown using javascript object. I should mention that I am getting this javascript object as a JSON response using AJAX from the server side.

```
     var fruits =
      {
        "1": {
              "id": 1,
              "Description": "Apple",
              "groupID": 0
             },
        "2": {
              "id": 2,
              "Description": "Peach",
              "groupID": 0
             }
      }
```

Can somebody direct me to a link to do so? or help me out with the code here? 
What I am doing currently

```
            dropdown1.options.length = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < fruits.length; i++) {
                var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
                option.innerHTML = fruits[i].Description;
                option.value = fruits[i].id;
                dropdown1.options.add(option);}
```

But everything is being printed as undefined.

Comment: What did you try? What is a "dropdown menu"? Loop over the object keys and build the HTML.

Comment: https://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-add-options-html-select/

Comment: Well you have an object and an object is not an array so for loop is not going to work.

Comment: well you are right.. Can we call it an array of objects? Can you suggest something?

Comment: some people - quick at downvoting but not so in helping with a solution

Comment: @user5673235 I gave you a link that walks you through doing exactly what you're trying to do..

Comment: its not the same

Comment: @user5673235 Not sure what you mean that it's not the same, but I posted a solution. Take a look and let me know if that's what you were looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having trouble understanding how your situation is different than the solution offered in [the article I linked](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/javascript-add-options-html-select/), but for the sake of demonstration, I created a solution using the concepts from the article combined with your original code.

```js
var fruits =
{
  "1": {
        "id": 1,
        "Description": "Apple",
        "groupID": 0
       },
  "2": {
        "id": 2,
        "Description": "Peach",
        "groupID": 0
       }
};
var _select = document.createElement("select");
for (var key in fruits) {
  var fruit = fruits[key];
  _select.options[_select.options.length] = new Option(fruit.Description, fruit.id);
}

document.body.appendChild(_select);
```